# Rails table name contains digits

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-models

Is it possible to use a table in rails that contains digits in its name?

I have a table named photo_2014_hierarchies

Its model is saved as photo_2014_hierarchy.rb

and inside I use

```
class Photo2014Hierarchy < ActiveRecord::Base
```

which works for other tables in this db

however when I try to use this table in a controller I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Photo2014Hierarchy
```

Comment: model file name should be `photo_2014_hierarchy.rb`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is not working is the detection of word boundaries in the `underscore` method:

```
> "Photo2014Hierarchy".underscore
  => "photo2014_hierarchy"
```

As you can see, the number is not considered a word to be divided by underscores. In your case this means that your file has to be named `photo2014_hierarchy.rb` and your table `photo2014_hierarchies`.

Note: `table_name` is only required if you can't change the table name accordingly as Rails knows how to pluralize hierarchy.

```
> "Photo2014Hierarchy".pluralize.underscore
  => "photo2014_hierarchies"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, yes. I wouldn't go creating dirty model names, but instead consider using [`table_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) in your models if you're having to work with a legacy naming convention.